# How do you update HTML5 canvas from angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a little canvas that draws a cross and an input box to control the angle of rotation.

```
 <input type='text' ng-model='angle'>
    <canvas id="myLitleCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myLitleCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.save();

      context.translate(100, 100);
      context.rotate({{angle}} * Math.PI / 180.0); // <---- problem
      context.translate(-100, -100);

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(100, 0);
      context.lineTo(100, 200);
      context.moveTo(0, 100);
      context.lineTo(200, 100);
      context.stroke();
    </script>
```

Then I have a very simple controller bound to `angle`

```
function MapCtrl($scope) { 
    $scope.angle = 45;
}
```

ButI can't seem to access `angle` or redraw the canvas when the value in the text box changes. Is this even possible?

Comment: as far as I know angular does not process scripts, so your `{{angle}}` has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no token replacement in javascript blocks. The recommended way of doing DOM manipulation is to put your javascript code into a directive. You would then have an attribute that references your 'angle' parameter. You might want to look at [angular-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui) for ideas on doing custom UI directives. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, there is no token replacement in javascript blocks.

To get this working...move the code from the script block with the controller. And just simply access the angle as `$scope.angle`. You could also write a `rotateAndRedraw` function and bind to `ng-click` or whatever:

```
$scope.rotateAndRedraw = function (angle) {
      context.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
      context.translate(100, 100);
      context.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
      context.translate(-100, -100);

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(100, 0);
      context.lineTo(100, 200);
      context.moveTo(0, 100);
      context.lineTo(200, 100);
      context.stroke();
};
```

You could also wrap all this canvas code within a directive and easily replicate the canvas multiple times on a page.